# Make datatable table head select options depend on another table head select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a `datatable` with two columns having their table head as select inputs to filter out data in the table.

[image]

This is my html code

```
<table id="dataTableInventory" class="table table-striped table-bordered data-table-drafts" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="filterhead" style="display: none;">Item ID</th>
            <th class="filterhead">Main Category</th>
            <th class="filterhead">Sub Category 1</th>
            <th class="filterhead">Sub Category 2</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Count</th>
            <th>In Stock</th>
            <th>Out Stock</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody id="table-body">
        <?php foreach($param_items as $item){?>
            <tr>
                <td class="id" style="display: none;"><?php echo $item['idx'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['main_category'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['sub_category_1'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['sub_category_2'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['item_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['in_stock']+$item['out_stock'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['in_stock'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['out_stock'];?></td>
                <td align="center"> /* some buttons here */</td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my javascript code for adding the select inputs in the table head:-

```
var table = $("#dataTableInventory").DataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 1, 2, 7 ] } ]
});
$(".filterhead").each( function ( i ) {
    console.log(i);
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo( $(this) )
        .on( 'change', function () {
           var term = $(this).val();
            table.column( i ).search(term, false, false ).draw();
        });
    table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
    });
});
```

Now my problem is when I choose the Main Category Computer, It also shows the Sub Category Grammar in the sub category select. How do I alter my code where when I choose a main category and the select in the sub category will only show the sub categories under the main category.

Comment: please provide HTML code also.

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel added my html code already. sorry